# C# string Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, string, alias

Hi i'm currently using Thread.Sleep(200); in between text for it to look like old pokemon game with the text not appearing all at once but going a bit laggy word for word like this

```
Console.Write("help"); Thread.Sleep(200); Console.Write("me");
```

And i'm wondering if you can name/shorten the `Thread.Sleep(200)` to something like `Ts200`. (I mean to text). So it's not much clutter.
So it would be something like this with a string.

```
string Ts200
Ts200 = Thread.Sleep(200)
Console.Write("help"); Ts200; Console.Write("me")
```

But it's not working.

I get this error:

> cannot implicitly convert type void to string

Comment: Please show us your complete code and not the pseudo one.

Comment: that's not how you define a string. the output of `Thread.Sleep` and `Console.Write` are *not* strings, so you can't use them to assign a string.
If this is a simple console application, The `write` and `sleep` calls should be in your `main` method

Comment: Create a function called Ts200 and call it each time, but you will learn soon that is a bad coding standard... there is nothing with Thread.Sleep(200)

Comment: what @EGN said, or you can edit the `Console.Write` code to automatically sleep for 200 ms before writing anything

Answer (score 4):

a simple way to do this would be to `split` the strings into arrays on spaces, then loop over them.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static void slowType(string fullSentence, int millis_pause)
{
   string[] words = fullSentence.Split(' ');
   foreach(string s in words)
   {
       Console.Out.Write(s);
       Thread.Sleep(millis_pause);
       //we must reintroduce the space, since we were splitting on it.
       Console.Out.Write(' ');
   }
   //optionally ; start a new line at the end of the sentence
   Console.Out.Write("\r\n");
}
```

usage example :

```
public static void Main()
{
    string sentence = "i am a terribly slow typist";
    slowType(sentence, 200);
}
```

Comment: I was just starting to write pretty much the same thing :-)

Comment: you could even do this per-character if you remove the split token

Comment: If you were going to use this in an actual game, `Thread.Sleep` would be a dangerous option (because you would require the dialogue to run in its own thread). but you would probably also have a timed update and/or render loop, so you would use *that* instead.

Comment: As @TimothyGroote said `Thread.Sleep()` is not a good choice. Rather go with `Task.Delay` or in WinForms with the `Backgroundworker` and work with those if it´s a choice for you.

Comment: @L.Guthardt Task.Delay introduces more complexity than `Thread.Sleep`, and you will likely end up with the same problems.
The `Backgroundworker` is designed for that kind of stuff, but will also require that you learn about cross-thread messaging and invoking. not beginner's stuff.

Comment: in other words ; for this kind of console application, i think `Thread.Sleep` is OK ;)

Comment: @TimothyGroote Agreed. Start with this, but keep in mind: In the art of programming there are so many ways how to achieve your goal and you might stumble quite often over a better solution. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try *lambda* if you don't mind `()` after `Ts200`:

```
Action Ts200 = () => Thread.Sleep(200); 

...

Ts200();
```

However, even if it's possile `Ts200()` is far less readable than `Thread.Sleep(200)`, that's why don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

You call the `Thread.Sleep(200);` on its own, it doesnt contain any value. So you cant return any value neither can you allocate it any value, except as the method parameter `Thread.Sleep("Here belongs the method parameter, this method accepts an 'int' value")`. The `int` method parameter sets for how many milli seconds you want to pause the mainthread.

---

Try something like this:

The `main` method is the entry point in your application once it gets executed. So when you start your application, you call the `main` method and execute it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sentence = "Here you enter your sentence...";
    string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

    OutputDelayedText(words);
}
```

The `string sentence` is the `string` variable that contains the sentence you want to ouput on the console. So we split the sentence into single words with the method `.Split(' ')`. This splits the spring on each space `' '` and puts the single words into a `string[]` array. Note that you have to use in the `.Split('')` method these `''` instead of what you are probably used to `""`. Thats because the method accepts a `char` value and those `''` indicate that you just put a single char in as the method parameter.

So in the end we call the `OutputDelayedText()` method with our word `array` as method parameter.

```
private static void OutputDelayedText(string[] myText)
{
    foreach (var word in myText)
    {
        Console.Write(word + " ");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Now we use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the array and write every single element of our array (one single word of our sentence) in one line on the console. If you are not familiar with `foreach` you could use either a `for` or `while` loop as well.

In generell i advice you to use `Task.Delay()`. Or in WinForms the `Backgroundworker`, those will allow you to work on different threads and if you pause those threads you dont pause your main thread. You will come across this issue later, this is used to pause any process or to execute a long task in the background to not freeze your GUI when the task is still running.

**However** just start with `Thread.Sleep()`, but keep in mind: In the art of programming are so many ways how to achieve your goal and you might stumble quite often over a better solution.